# Selenium doesnt pass web site security

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to make automation project.I have started to learn bs4 selenium little bit scrapy.I have successfully take content in normal sites.But some sites doesnt give permission automation.just like gmail site. Is there any relationship with using under remote control ?Is possible to disable remote control mode ? I can go site with webdriver modul but how can i reach website source with webdriver?
using browser firefox and chromium
os =ubuntu

```
    website='https://www.paribu.com/#/'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(website)
```

Comment: I didn't understood your question....do you want to make selenium "undetectable"?

Comment: I just want to enter web site.But Site detects me even i didnt banned. Every try site detects bots. Hoy can i pass detection

Comment: I'm gonna paste you a snippet with configuration for Chrome-Chromium. I think you should switch to it, more stable than Firefox in my point of View.

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome, to make it "undetectable" to most sites.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () =>  undefined})");
```

The last JS instruction serves to set the navigator variable of Chrome to undefined, like a non bot-controlled browser. Anyway to be safer you should modify the HEX of your binary using softwares like Okteta if you're on linux.

[Take a look here](https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/does-anyone-have-an-undetectable-selenium-jar.962732/page-2)

Answer (score 0):

To get the source page you can use
`driver.page_source`

if you want to make automation on very popular websites then always keep in mind these things

1. Sometimes don't just get URL directly, you will get detected ASAP, So try to go through duckduckgo search engine. Don't use the google search engine, they will also block your bot asap.
   First, go to duckduckgo.com,
   Search Gmail in the search bar
   then click on the Gmail link.
2. **always enable the cookies** with the selenium whenever you use
   or you can also feed some cookies.

   ```
   url = 'https://www.facebook.com/';

   cookies = json.load(open("cookies.json", "rb"))

   for cookie in cookies:

       driver.add_cookie(cookie)

   driver.get(url)
   ```
3. Always use the **latest user agent**.

   ```
   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

   profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36')

   driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
   ```
4. **Don't make your bot very fast to get detected**, you can time function or some selenium waits

   time.sleep(2)
5. **Use proxy** when required, even you can **use VPN** to make things simple.

After this, you would be able to bypass the protection of most of the websites.

**still, I think you need to elaborate on the question more.